# How to deploy .WAR in Jboss/tomcat:8 container

Tags: tomcat, jboss

I have some .WAR files and we are deploying them in docker container (tomcat:8).
This worked fine. Our dockerfile looked like this (simple version):

```
FROM tomcat:8
COPY webapps/ /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

Our .war's are stored in the webapps folder (poc concept).
Now we want to move to OpenShift of Red Hat. OpenShift doesn't allow to run containers as root (like the docker tomcat container). Than you have to ease the security. So we want to move our webapps to a jboss tomcat container (which isn't running as root). But where do we have to put our /webapps folder? We tried the same place but the logs don't show a deployment:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-webserver-3/webserver30-tomcat8-openshift
COPY webapps/ /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

Comment: You can put your war into `...../jboss/standalone/deployments` . Or use maven plugin to deploy if you're using maven to build your project

Comment: ...and please stop running tomcat as root. It's good that OpenShift doesn't allow this horrible idea.